# Create a custom node in drupal by PHP

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

I have a created a PHP file that takes parameters from URL and creates a drupal node in drupal 7

CODE:

```
include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$node=new stdClass;
$node->title='ABCD';
$node->type='order';
$node->language=LANGUAGE_NONE;
$node->uid=1;
$node->field_name['und'][0]['value']='ABC';
$node->field_contact['und'][0]['value']='1234567890';
$node->field_addr['und'][0]['value']='LMNOPQRST';
$node->field_email['und'][0]['value']='abc@abc.com';
$node->field_orderdetails['und'][0]['value']='fgheghfgjhgfhj';
$node->field_transaddr['und'][0]['value']='hdfghwgfhwgj';
$node->field_outletid['und'][0]['value']='MCK01';
node_save($node);

?>
```

Do i need to specify in drupal about this node creation through PHP?..

I am new to drupal.Thank in advance

Comment: Don't need to specify - just make sure that all required fields are in $node object. I can aslo suggest to add field $node-status=1 to publish node (or =0 to make it unpublished)

Comment: Thank you @VadimEremeev So in drupal i dont need to write any code?..Correct this much will create a new node in my drupal and will be visible in my website?..

Comment: why do you want to do that externally from other php page? Drupal can handle everything you need out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is enough to create the node. 
Here are some changes to fine tune:

```
include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'order';
node_object_prepare($node); // Prepare node object with default values. 

$node->title = 'ABCD';
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // LANGUAGE_NONE is a constant with value "und".
$node->uid = 1;
$node->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']='ABC';
$node->field_contact[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']='1234567890';
$node->field_addr[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']='LMNOPQRST';
$node->field_email[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']='abc@abc.com';
$node->field_orderdetails[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']='fgheghfgjhgfhj';
$node->field_transaddr[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']='hdfghwgfhwgj';
$node->field_outletid[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']='MCK01';

node_save($node);
```

However, there is no need to use this snippet as an external file. 
Drupal is full of [hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7) and/or you can implement [`hook_cron`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) to execute your code during maintenance time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine.
Only what you need to do is to trigger it at specific event (on menu, or any node add/edit/delete event).